# New ipython notebook templating

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Is it possible to define some template content cells which all new ipython notebooks include when being created?

I'd like my notebooks to include some standard CSS using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18199211) and possibly also have a markdown cell with links I'm frequently using .

Comment: to include custom CSS in any notebook (new and old) the custom.css file can be used.

Comment: @Jacob thanks for the pointer. Is there somewhere a description of the css classes?

Comment: You may check http://zulko.wordpress.com/2013/04/14/customize-your-ipython-notebook-with-css/ and http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/1cbn2p/ipython_notebook_10_allows_custom_styling_with/ so far I'm not aware of any real documentation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to @Jakob for the help.

To get permanent customised CSS within the notebooks, I needed to create `<myprofile>/static/custom/custom.css` in my `.ipython` user folder folder.

This worked quite ok. I used the firefox's webdev tools to find the css items and classes in the ipython notebook and managed to get a monokai-ish style:

[image: ipython notebook with monokai style]

I also learned from [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/raw.github.com/Carreau/posts/master/02-css-selector.ipynb) that you can inject javascript which might make it possible to add default content to new notebooks. I haven't tried this one yet though.

Edit: if interested, the css file lives [here](https://github.com/panditarevolution/ipythonNotebook_customs/tree/master/monokai). The monokai colors are based on `.cm-s-ipython`, which I think is similar what sublime text is using.