# pre-filled cells in new ipython notebook

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

When I make a new ipython notebook, I would like to have a pre-filled one.

By pre-filled, I mean that instead of a first blank cell, I would like in it a custom code like

```
import os
import sys
...
```

In other words, I do not want to type or copy/paste in every notebook the same piece of code I use 90% of my time.

I do not want this code to be executed behind the scene. It should appear in the notebook.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850829/new-ipython-notebook-templating

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto-Loading a module from \_\_future\_\_ on IPython startup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20835977/auto-loading-a-module-from-future-on-ipython-startup)