# Default template for iPython notebook (using Jupyter)

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

In the first cell of every iPython (Jupyter) notebook, I almost always type:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
```

Is there a way to make it so that this cell appears at the top of each new notebook I create by default?

For example, could I save a template `.ipynb` file somewhere, which is copied by iPython when creating a new notebook?

(I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19850829/279858), but it seems to be more about css than default content in cells.)

Comment: I think this would be useful. I don't think this exists at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a pretty cool solution using **jupyterlab**: 
[jupyterlab_templates](https://github.com/timkpaine/jupyterlab_templates)

Installation took about 5 minutes and you can have as many

templates as you'd like.

#### Mac Users

Assuming you have conda installed than during the installation, you'll need to install node js engine:

- `conda install -c conda-forge nodejs`

And create a jupter_noteook_config.py if you don't have one :

- `jupyter notebook --generate-config`

Comment: This is definitely the closest to my original request, and it is nice that you can have a set of different templates.

Answer (score 11):

I know it may not be what you're looking for (this example is not good for working on notebooks that need to be run in multiple environments, e.g. shared), but I put the following in a file called `ipython_config.py` in my `.ipython` folder.

```
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = ['%matplotlib inline',
    'import numpy as np',
    'import scipy.constants as scc',
    'import scipy.integrate as sci',
    'from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D',
    'import scipy.optimize as sco'
]
```

This runs before anything runs in any interactive console, including the jupyter notebook. If you want explicit boilerplating, I think that you will be disappointed (unless you want to build in the functionality for us ☺)

Comment: Setting up the implicit imports in the config spoils the portability of the notebooks. It would be much better to have a template with explicit imports for clarity because in the Zen of Python: "Explicit is better than implicit".

Comment: I keep revisiting this question myself to see if someone has figured it out. I think that it could be done with a customization of the pre_save_hook that jupyter uses when it saves a notebook, but I still haven't figured it out.

Comment: This is a hack but works. I keep a startup.py (several) file which is simply a case in Jupyter of calling %load startup.py. Nothing more than a quick-type but it works...

Comment: It would be so cool if we could install templates, which would end up under the "New" dropdown menu from the Jupyter file browser..

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with ipython startup files. Create a new startup file in the default profile and it'll be pulled in by jupyter automatically when it starts ipython.

```
 ~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/00-startup.py
```

Comment: this is a nice solution but it does not textually adds the header to the notebook. This is problem when sharing nbs with other people since the import are not shared.