# <code> tag not styling properly in ipython notebook

Tags: html, css, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to use the `<code>` tag in a markdown cell of an ipython notebook.  However the expected styling behavior is being over written:

*[image: renderedhtml.less]*

I've tried:

- over writing the default custom.css per [here](http://blog.henryhhammond.com/theming-ipython/): doesn't work
- add a custom code cell that loads a custom.css per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024769/adding-custom-styled-paragraphs-in-markdown-cells/#answer-18199211): doesn't work
- adding a `<style>` definition within the cell containing the `<code>` tag: doesn't work
- adding the style in-line to the `<code>` tag: this works

Anyone know how I prevent this style from being over-written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was using the wrong tags to define the css; I followed [the guide here](http://blog.henryhhammond.com/theming-ipython/) and then set the CSS style with

```
.rendered_html code {
    padding:2px 4px;
    font-size: 90%;
    color: #c7254e;
    background-color: #f9f2f4;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```