# How to increase the font size of the markdown table in jupyter notebook?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, markdown

I have a juptyer notebook with a markdown cell

```
# Projects

<div style="font-size: 50px">

hello

| Project                      |Project Type       | Status                |
|------------------------------|-------------------|-----------------------|
|   Hello phase 1              |ABC                |Ongoing                |
|   Goodbye analytics          |EFG                |Completed              |

</div >
```

But it does not increase the font size of the words inside the table, and it only increases the font size of "Hello".

Is it possible to increase the font size of the words inside the table? Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For jupyter-notebooks you can use the `%%HTML` magic. Place the code below inside a notebook code cell:

```css
%%HTML

<style>
td,th {
  font-size: 15px
}
</style>
```

Depending on your jupyter version, [other approaches might work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024769/adding-custom-styled-paragraphs-in-markdown-cells).

Comment: Where do I add this?  I add it in the same cell, but it doesn't work  

    <style>
    td {
      font-size: 50px
    }
    </style>hello

    | Project                      |Project Type       | Status                |
    |------------------------------|-------------------|-----------------------|
    |   Hello phase 1              |ABC                |Ongoing                |
    |   Goodbye analytics          |EFG                |Completed              |

Comment: add it just at the top of your document for example. but as i said, might depend on your version...

Comment: it works! I need to add your code in a code cell, and start with

%%HTML

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Works for me too! The element name was:
.rendered_html table

Comment: Thank you so very much!

Answer (score 3):

You may try this:
Add html tag inside the cells which is annoying but useful for now

for example

```
|&#60;font size=4&#62;Project&#60;/font&#62;|&#60;font size=4&#62;Project Type&#60;/font&#62;|&#60;font size=4&#62;Status&#60;/font&#62;|<br>
|---|---|---|<br>
|&#60;font size=4&#62;Hello phase 1&#60;/font&#62;|&#60;font size=4&#62;ABC&#60;/font&#62;|&#60;font size=4&#62;Ongoing&#60;/font&#62;|<br>
|&#60;font size=4&#62;Goodbye analytics&#60;/font&#62;|&#60;font size=4&#62;EFG&#60;/font&#62;|&#60;font size=4&#62;Completed&#60;/font&#62;|
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also add it in custom.css:

```
.rendered_html table, .rendered_html td, .rendered_html th {
    font-size: 200%;
}
```

I also think you should be able to do it with just the `table` element (omitting the `td` and `th` elements).