# Color note boxes sintax not showing in Google Colab

Tags: html, jupyter-notebook, markdown, google-colaboratory

When using colored note boxes in jupyter notebooks,  the following text cell is not correctly rendered in Google Colab:

```
<div class="alert alert-block alert-info">
<b>Tip: </b>
Use blue boxes for Tips and notes. If it’s a note, you don’t have to include the word “Note”. 
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, I google my own question. I was using this to review the submisions of my pupils. Is there another way to clearly add revisions to a jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to run this on Colab instead. Don't forget to use the magic line `%%html`. I just modified the code of @user2304916 from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024769/adding-custom-styled-paragraphs-in-markdown-cells).

```
%%html
<style>
div.warn {    
    color: #356A89;
    background-color: #D4EAF7;
    border-left: 5px solid #3C82E3;
    padding: 0.5em;
    }
 </style>
<div class=warn>
Use blue boxes (alert-info) for tips and notes. 
If it’s a note, you don’t have to include the word “Note”.
</div>
```

> 

```html
<style>
div.warn {    
    color: #356A89;
    background-color: #D4EAF7;
    border-left: 5px solid #3C82E3;
    padding: 0.5em;
    }
 </style>
<div class=warn>
Use blue boxes (alert-info) for tips and notes. 
If it’s a note, you don’t have to include the word “Note”.
</div>
```

Comment: So you have to do that in every cell where you want this to happen? That is really inconvenient.

Comment: As a note - this seems to work in Colab by putting the HTML into a *code* chunk and running it, then hiding the output.